# Unable to send email address to Distribution list having spaces - Java

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am unable to send email to distribution list having below format

> MA NA US error@hub.wmmercer.com

```
InternetAddress[] mailtoArr = new InternetAddress[str.length];
for loop {
mailtoArr[i] = new InternetAddress((str[i].trim()));
}
```

It gives me below exception:

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal whitespace in address in string ``#MA NA US error@hub.wmmercer.com''
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.checkAddress(InternetAddress.java:900)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:793)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:529)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:65)
```

Someone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the address using [javax.internet.MimeUtility.quote(String,String)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#quote(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).  Here is an example:

```
public class DontQuoteMeOnIt {
    private static final String SPECIALS_NO_DOT = "()<>,;:\\\"[] \t";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "MA NA US error@hub.wmmercer.com";
        s = MimeUtility.quote(s, SPECIALS_NO_DOT);
        System.out.println(InternetAddress.parse(s, true)[0]);
    }
}
```